# Python Pandas shift by given value in cell within groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Given the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'name': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
                        'lag': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                        'value': range(10)})

print(df)

   lag name  value
0    1    a      0
1    1    a      1
2    1    a      2
3    2    b      3
4    2    b      4
5    2    b      5
6    2    b      6
7    2    c      7
8    2    c      8
9    2    c      9
```

I am trying to shift values contained in column `value` to obtain the column `expected_value`, which is the shifted values grouped by column `name` and shifted by `lag` rows. I was thinking of using something like `df['expected_value'] = df.groupby(['name', 'lag']).shift()`, but I am not sure how to pass `lag` to the `shift()` function.

```
print(df)

   lag name  value  expected_value
0    1    a      0             nan
1    1    a      1          0.0000
2    1    a      2          1.0000
3    2    b      3             nan
4    2    b      4             nan
5    2    b      5          3.0000
6    2    b      6          4.0000
7    2    c      7             nan
8    2    c      8             nan
9    2    c      9          7.0000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform) here.

```
df.assign(expected_value = df.groupby(['name', 'lag'])['value'].
                              transform(lambda x: x.shift(x.name[1])))


  name  lag  value  expected_value
0    a    1      0             NaN
1    a    1      1             0.0
2    a    1      2             1.0
3    b    2      3             NaN
4    b    2      4             NaN
5    b    2      5             3.0
6    b    2      6             4.0
7    c    2      7             NaN
8    c    2      8             NaN
9    c    2      9             7.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do with an `apply`:

```
df['new_val'] = (df.groupby('name')
   .apply(lambda x: x['value'].shift(x['lag'].iloc[0]))
   .reset_index('name',drop=True)
)
```

Output:

```
  name  lag  value  new_val
0    a    1      0      NaN
1    a    1      1      0.0
2    a    1      2      1.0
3    b    2      3      NaN
4    b    2      4      NaN
5    b    2      5      3.0
6    b    2      6      4.0
7    c    2      7      NaN
8    c    2      8      NaN
9    c    2      9      7.0
```

Comment: Do you know whether it would be possible without the apply()?

Comment: Probably not since the lag changes across the groups.